# IMessageService.ShowAsync in INavigationService.ApplicationClosing event

Tags: events, asynchronous, catel

How to?

I tried these two methods, but none works. The first hangs, the second quits the program (without any exception).

```
private void ApplicationClosing1(object sender, ApplicationClosingEventArgs e)
{
    MessageResult result = MessageResult.None;
    if (!isClosing && IsDirty)
    {
        result = MessageService.ShowAsync("blah", "blah",
            MessageButton.YesNoCancel, MessageImage.Warning)
            .GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        switch (result)
        {
            case MessageResult.Cancel:
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            case MessageResult.Yes:
                isClosing = true;
                SaveAsync();
                break;
            default:
                isClosing = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
private async void ApplicationClosing2(object sender, ApplicationClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isClosing && IsDirty)
    {
        var result = await MessageService.ShowAsync("blah","blah",
            MessageButton.YesNoCancel, MessageImage.Warning);

        switch (result)
        {
            case MessageResult.Cancel:
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            case MessageResult.Yes:
                isClosing = true;
                await SaveAsync();
                break;
            default:
                isClosing = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it the same way as the DataWindows takes care of this. First set e.Cancel = true, then if the user answers, set an internal bool `_reallyClose` and don't set e.Cancel when this is true.